# the difference between ridge and A\b in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Given the same `A`, `b` and L2 regularization parameter `beta = 0`, why do `ridge` and `\` give two different solutions?

```
b = [ 0
    -2
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3
    -3 ];

A = [
1   0   0   0
0.750000000000000   0.250000000000000   0   0
0.500000000000000   0.500000000000000   0   0
0.250000000000000   0.750000000000000   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0.750000000000000   0.250000000000000   0
0   0.500000000000000   0.500000000000000   0
0   0.250000000000000   0.750000000000000   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   0.750000000000000   0.250000000000000
0   0   0.500000000000000   0.500000000000000
0   0   0.250000000000000   0.750000000000000
0   0   0   1
];

>> ridge(b, A, 0,0)
ans = 
    0.6942
   -0.1856
         0
   -0.0468

>> A \ b
ans = 
   -0.8604
   -3.4188
   -2.8970
   -3.0343
```

Comment: Please try to format your posts properly. Also try to use simpler examples.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `ridge(b,A,0,1)`? Or read the [`ridge` function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/ridge.html) help?

Answer (score 1):

That's because, as you can se in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ridge.html), `ridge` uses a slightly different algorithm  than `mldivide`: since the "classical" pseudoinverse (*(A'* **A)^-1* **A*) could become sensible to small errors for *(A'* **A)^-1* close to singular values, the formula  is modified to *(A'* **A - kI)^-1* **A*, reducing the conditioning of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but this response is wrong for several reasons. First of all, ridge does NOT use the expression you show. It uses a numerically stable version that uses \ instead. The point is, if you are going to talk about conditioning problems, then using a numerically poor formula is silly in the extreme! As well, the "classical" pseudo-inverse is best never written using a matrix inverse. Instead, use x=A\y.

Comment: I know about the conditioning issue. What I wanna ask is that why they produce different solutions even if I choose k=0 in  (A' *A - kI)^-1. In this case, I think / 's solution is more desirable.